# How can we pass multiple filters to OData read

Tags: sapui5

I have come across with situation where more than 10 input values has to be passed to back end as filters. Is there any other option to create and pass filters instead of creating it in controller for each input filed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have more sophisticated way of controlling the filter stuff declaratively via the XML view, for example, you can go with the following approach:

1. Assign to all the affected inputs a "customData" property, defining the "filterProperty" and "filterOperation"
2. Assign to all affected inputs the same "fieldGroupId"
3. On the filter button trigger, grab all the input via the "getControlsByFieldGroupId" method and construct the filters using the custom data form each input via the "data" function call

for using custom data include the namespace to the view:
`xmlns:data="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"`

[customData doc](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#addCustomData)

in XML:

`<Input fieldGroupIds="InputGroup" data:filterName="Id" data:filterOperation="EQ" />
<Input fieldGroupIds="InputGroup" data:filterName="Name" data:filterOperation="Constains" />
<Input fieldGroupIds="InputGroup" data:filterName="Color" data:filterOperation="LT" />`

in JS:

`var aInputs = oView.getControlsByFieldGroupId("InputGroup");`

```
var aFilters = aInputs.map(function(oInput) {
    var sFilterName = oInput.data("filterName");
    var sFilterOperation = oInput.data("filterOperation");

    return new Filter(sFilterName, sFilterOperation, oInput.getValue());
});
```

[See example](https://jsbin.com/wipefal/edit?html,js,output%20See%20Example)

Answer (score 0):

You can create filter for every input and push it to the array of filters which you will use as you need.

E.g.:

```
var oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Input1", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value1);
var oFilter2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Input2", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value2);
var oFilter3 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Input3", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value3);
var oFilter4 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Input4", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, value4);
var allFilters = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oFilter1, oFilter2, oFilter3, oFilter4], false);
```

For more info look [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
    //Create an array
    var aFilters = [];
        if (yourVal1) {
            aFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Dimension", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, yourVal1));
        }
        if (yourVal2) {
            aFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Language", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, yourVal1));
        }

        this.getModel().read("/YourEntitySet", {
            filters: aFilters,
            success: function(oData) {
                // use the response as required.
            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
```